# SQL select unique based on value

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table:

```
Name | Value | Prize
Race1   32      5
Race1   22      5
Race1   30      5
Race2   11      5
Race2   12      5
Race2   31      5
```

What I want to query, When I define a `Value` 20+, The UNIQUE races (Race1, Race2) will be selected to my result, based on whose `Value` is higher. And prize should be summed.

So when I do metaquery : `select sum(Prize) biggestValueUniqueRaces  where value > -20`
I get:

Query returns :

```
Prize
  10
```

Where it took into consideration these 2 rows :

```
Name | Value | Prize
Race1   32      5
Race2   31      5
```

Comment: Could there be any duplicates in Value for the same race?

Comment: Yes. The chance of that occuring is low, but still may happen. When that occurs, It doesnt matter which it takes.

Comment: @Remou I don't see any answer here yet. not even yours.

Comment: Do you have a unique ID? It would be a lot easier with one.

Comment: @Remou Only autogenerated unique ID. Each row has 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc.

Comment: Always worth mentioning, however, I have added another query that may suit. I will get back with one using the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit re comment

```
SELECT Sum(Races.Prize) As Total
FROM Races INNER JOIN (SELECT r.[Name], Max(r.[Value]) AS MaxOfValue
FROM Races r WHERE [Value]>20
GROUP BY r.[Name])  AS q 
ON (Races.Value = q.MaxOfValue) AND (Races.Name = q.Name);
```

Or

```
SELECT SUM(races.prize) AS SP
FROM   races
WHERE  races.id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM   races r
    WHERE  r.name = races.name
    AND VALUE = (
       SELECT Max(VALUE)
       FROM   races s
       WHERE  s.[name] = r.name
       AND VALUE > 20 ))
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesnt return for example this also? `Race1   22      5` . What guarantees the first query to return the biggest of values?

Answer (score 2):

You first have to determine all races, for which the Value is equal to the maximum Value of the races with the same name.

```
SELECT
    [r1].[Name],
    [r1].[Value],
    [r1].[Prize]
  FROM [Races] [r1]
  WHERE [r1].[Value] > 20
    AND [r1].[Value] = 
      (SELECT MAX([r2].[Value])
       FROM [Races] [r2]
       WHERE [r2].[Name] = [r1].[Name])
```

This could give multiple races with the same Name, Value and Prize. So group them:

```
SELECT
    [r1].[Name],
    [r1].[Value],
    [r1].[Prize]
  FROM [Races] [r1]
  WHERE [r1].[Value] > 20
    AND [r1].[Value] = 
      (SELECT MAX([r2].[Value])
       FROM [Races] [r2]
       WHERE [r2].[Name] = [r1].[Name])
  GROUP BY 
    [r1].[Name],
    [r1].[Value],
    [r1].[Prize]
```

And then sum the prizes:

```
SELECT
  SUM([sub].[Prize]) AS [TotalPrizes],
  COUNT(*) AS [NumberOfRaces]
FROM
(
  SELECT
    [r1].[Name],
    [r1].[Value],
    [r1].[Prize]
  FROM [Races] [r1]
  WHERE [r1].[Value] > 20
    AND [r1].[Value] = 
      (SELECT MAX([r2].[Value])
       FROM [Races] [r2]
       WHERE [r2].[Name] = [r1].[Name])
  GROUP BY 
    [r1].[Name],
    [r1].[Value],
    [r1].[Prize]
) AS [sub]
```

[Here is a Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb24f/11). (I set server type to MS SQL 2008, but I don't think that will be a problem for this case/query).

Comment: That is why I added the comment. There are no parts in this query, which are not available in MS Access, that I'm aware of.

Comment: DECLARE @minimum int = 20 is not available.

Comment: Not the main part of my answer, I guess, but I corrected it. Thanks for telling me.